# Powershell GPUpdate @list - cannot connect to computers? Syntax?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

When I run the script below here's what I get:

PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

*\ ■B:
Couldn't access  ■B:
The network path was not found.
Make sure that the default admin$ share is enabled on  ■B.*

I checked that the computers.txt list is valid (it's intentionally setup to just run on the one ou now to test)

Here's the code:

```
# refresh gp for logged in user
param(
$ouInfo
)

#make computer list
cls
Write-Host "Group Policy Update for User(s) on Remote Computer(s)`nBy xxxx`r" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$manOrAuto = Read-Host = "Enter computer name(s) Manually or Import from location? (m or i)"

if ($manOrAuto -eq "m")
    {
    New-Item c:\computers.txt -type file -Force
    cls
    Write-Host "Group Policy Update for User(s) on Remote Computer(s)`nBy Tom Gipson - txxxxx@xxxx`r" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    do {
    $computarList = Read-Host "Enter the name of the computer or IP address:"
    [string]$addSitesToList = "`r" + $computarList + "`r`n"
    Add-Content -Path c:\computers.txt -Value $addSitesToList
    Read-Host [string]$runAgain = "Add another? (y or n)"
    } while ($runAgain -eq "y")

    #update gp for logged in user
    Psexec.exe @c:\computers.txt Gpupdate.exe /Target:User /force
    }
    else {if ($manOrAuto -eq "i"){
    #get list of computers from AD
    New-Item c:\computers.txt -type file -Force
    cls
    Write-Host "Group Policy Update for User(s) on Remote Computer(s)`nBy xxxxxx - txxxx@vxxxxxx`r" -ForegroundColor Yellow

    #get location
    Write-Host "Locations:`r" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host "xxxx`mxxxx`nxxxx`netc`n`r" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $branchLocation = Read-Host "Enter the location from the list above and hit enter:"

    $ouInfoPrefix = "'OU=xxxxxxx,OU="
    $ouInfoSuffix = ",OU=xxxxx,OU=xxxxxx,dc=xxxxxxx,dc=local'"
    [string]$ouInfo = $ouInfoPrefix + $branchLocation + $ouInfoSuffix

    Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=Computers,OU=xxxxxx,OU=xxxxxx,OU=vxxxxx,dc=xxxxxx,dc=local' -Filter '*' | Select -Expand Name | Out-File c:\computers.txt
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    Psexec.exe @c:\computers.txt cmd /c Gpupdate.exe /force
    }}
```

Comment: You want to start that line to be parsed by the simple command parser (I think that's the right term, Keith Hill would know off the top of his head). Do `PSExec.exe --% @c:\computers.txt gpupdate.exe /target:user /force` and see if that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician thanks--doesn't work tho as it's still giving me the same output.  It's like it thinks the first computer in the list is a share location.  The first one in the list is: **BR-TELL-01** if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to fix this by forcing the out-file encoding to ASCII (default is Unicode)

```
out-file -encoding ASCII
```

Comment: Ah, I thought PowerShell was trying to Splat an array that didn't exist due to the @ symbol. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: yeah, i remembered before it would spit out text files in Chinese (literally) when using out-file or append commands--the ascii encoding fixed it